# Android: Socket connection from Device to PC Emulator

Tags: android, sockets, connection, emulation, device

**Note:** I'm asking this only because other solutions I've seen to the same or similar problems haven't worked.

**Situation**: I've written a client-server app, that runs fine if the client and the server are both emulators on the PC. A simple socket connection is established by using Telnet.

**Problem:** Now I want the client to be a real Android device. A USB wire is used for connection. The "USB Debugging" mode is on.

But, no connectivity takes place between the device and the emulator.

**What I've done**: I obtain the socket to the server using the following line:

thisSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("My-PC").getHostAddress(), SERVERPORT);

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have not found answers because this is simply not supported by the tools.  ADB's netowrking provisions, specifically forwarding, only work when the PC initiates connection to the device, and not the other way around.  Further, even if you put them on a common wifi network, the emulator does not listen on external interfaces, the emulator can't accept connections from external interfaces.  You might be able to get somewhere by activating a tethering solution (watch out for unintended routing of other traffic though!).  Probably you'll need two devices on wifi, but even that is tricky.

Comment: Hi Chris. So does that mean I cannot send a message from a device to an emulator using a socket connection ? Do I have to use intermediary devices/servers/proxies ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means - except perhaps the tethering hack but I would not recommend that.  At some point you have to ask what your goal is - directly communicating between Android devices is generally not possible (with the same-wifi exception) so how will your program work when deployed?

Comment: OK. So I think I'll have to build a tether residing on the same machine as the server, that listens to messages from external devices. Then, it will pass them on to the emulator (server).

Comment: Chris, do you also know how to connect a USB Tethered device to the machine's network ?

Comment: Tethering typically creates a network between the two as a side effect, but this is not the intended usage so you are on your own.