# Android: Can Android client talk to Java Proxy server?

Tags: android, proxy, client-server

**Situation** : An Android client-server application has been developed. Currently the client and the server are 2 emulators running on the same machine.

**Problem**: The server will remain an emulator. But the client can be an external device. And such devices cannot directly communicate with emulators. So, a Proxy server must be developed (in Java).

Can an Android client (external device) communicate with a Java Proxy server?

Comment: Yes. Android is nothing special, it can do all the things. Also, who came up with that proxy idea? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection

Comment: Hi zapl. But wasn't an emulator not supposed to listen to external devices? I've read about a proxy server residing between the external device and the emulator.....So, how else does an external device  connect with an emulator?

Comment: It is shielded by default but you can expose it like the documentation [or this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator) describes . You basically setup some routing rules that map ports on your server to ports inside the emulator.

Comment: zapl, one last thing: I had asked this question some days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845719/android-socket-connection-from-device-to-pc-emulator

And that's why I concluded a proxy server may be needed. Port redirection really works ?

Comment: Why do you want to connect the real device via USB to the server? Just let the Phone connect to some WiFi and connect to the IP of your server.

Comment: take a look at genymotion emulators. Not only they run at real device speeds, but network stack is fully functional, you can connect to them just like to a normal device.

Comment: rupps, I'll consider that. zapl, I'm trying this example that mentions what you say: http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/tag/client/